# Android Keyword Error when installing Phonegap

Tags: android, bash, cordova

I am having the following error when running the command: `cordova platform add android`. I already have ant installed and node/npm installed.

My bash profile is this:

```
export PATH=/Users/chaitanyavaranasi/local/bin:$PATH
export PATH=${PATH}:/Users/chaitanyavaranasi/android-sdks/platform-tools:/Users/chaitanyavaranasi/android-sdks/tools
```

The overall error I get is:

```
Error: The command "android" failed. Make sure you have the latest Android SDK installed, and the "android" command (inside the tools/ folder) is added to your path.
```

Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should exec the SDK Manager in the folder

```
/chaitanyavaranasi/android-sdks
```

and install the Android SDK

Comment: how do i exactly install it? the sdk is a set of folders. i just placed it in my applications

Comment: Sorry I confused with Windows, in MAC with ADT Bundle you could exec the Eclipse and click on "Android SDK Manager" there you can install toold, extras and Android APIs. In Linux will be similar.

Comment: Also in shell, with `platforms-tools` and `tools` in `PATH` system variable, you could use the `android` command and it will run the `Android SDK Manager`.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you need to close your shell and open a new one.